# Double/single-spacing for Gmail under Windows 7/8 with Chrome?

Tags: gmail

I must have hit some magic keystroke. Suddenly using the most recent copies of Gmail, Chrome, with those 7/8, etc. I'm getting double-spacing in Gmail for the Unreads and Everything Else. Until today it was always single-spaced (I used to have perhaps 15 items under everything else, now only eight or so fit).

Is there a cure? What was the cause, anyway?

Also, is there a "switch" that would hide the *read* messages?

Answer (score 1):

#### I'm getting double-spacing in Gmail for the Unreads

1. Click `Settings`
2. Select `Compact`

[image]

---

#### Is there a "switch" that would hide the read messages?

One option is to [Archive](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6576?hl=en) your read messages.

What I find easier is to configure your Inbox to have Unread messages listed first:

1. Click on the popdown arrow at the right of your `Inbox`
2. Select `Unread First`.

[image]

3. Now your inbox messages are in two expandable groups

   - Unread
   - Everything else

[image]

4. Expanding `Unread` shows **only** Unread messages (the Read messages are hidden in Everything else).

Comment: Well, I'm getting there. I'm not sure of the right combination but using the search box and some combination of "is: read"/"is: unread"/"in: <named- section>" And some other stuff gets me a lot closer to what I have in mind. And now you know how I will be spending my weekend. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems something is wrong with your formatting either in your browser or computer. Have you tried reinstalling chrome? This was a [highly-occurring](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/OktRyua_50M) issue in past versions. Other users also found that **switching the display view to 'compact'** via settings solved the issue. (Ran out of links, its on techguy.org)

You should be able to use [Shift + Enter](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r21932742-How-to-stop-double-spacing-in-gmail) to manually do single-spaced lines. You can also **switch to plain text mode** in the bottom right corner of the message composer.

By switch to hide read messages, you can **click the triangle next to the select all button to have options to select categories of messages.** Read and unread are included. It's up to you what you do with them from there :)

Comment: One out of two is not a bad average! Switching to "compact" is even better than what I recall single-spacing to be. However switching back and forth between read/unread Doesn't do what I want it to. Switching back and forth selects the desired messages but leaves the other messages still visible. Let's say that I have 100 messages, and have read every other message. What I want to be able to do is to pick the read messages (say)and have only the 50 messages that are read (or unread) be displayed. The others are "invisible"

Comment: You want it to not show messages after you read them by default? Like an auto-move to a folder?

Comment: That would work, but would be sub-optimal: I would lose any context. Preferably I would prefer to simply have a hide/unhide button. But in auto-move to a folder would work – but it needs a better name!

Comment: You might be able to use the 'Smartlabels' Google Lab function, and add custom filters for it to use. Or, you could create 'Read' and 'Unread' categories or labels, and switch between the two.

Comment: @krich - Using "Unread first" splits the inbox into two expandable categories - Unread emails and Everything else. See my answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Yep, that works perfectly on my end. Great find!